# Simple List & List using Database Values

Tags: android

i need some suggestions first,

1. My application is like, on main screen a user clicks the image button "Courses" and navigates to a list, with three items, when user touches any item, he moves into another "List view" that pick up values from the database, and then if a user clicks on any item of second list,will be navigated to final view or a webview..

suggestion i need is, is it a nice practice to navigate a user from list to another list, in a
application..

and in Iphone application they make back button to each view,(as they dont have a back button on iphone) but in many android applications i didn;t seen back button in list view layout, do i need to have a back button on the top of the list view ?

1. Second question i have is, do i really have to make a Database for a list, 
    i have to make atleast 6 or 7 Lists in my application, with some list having values nearly 16

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a few comments on these:

1) The application might end up having a complex navigation to achieve simple tasks if there are multiple levels of lists. Consider using a Tab layout instead of the first level list, since you mentioned there are only 3 entries in the first list. Also try to consolidate your menus so that user can view options upfront

2) Back button: IMHO in android you should only implement it iff you want to override the default behaviour of the back button.

3) Database for a list: Totally depends on whether you want to change the lists once the app is installed. If they are static then you dont need to build it from the database

Answer (score 1):

Ad. 1: No, you don't need back button in list view. It's real back button in all android devices.

Ad. 2: No. But when data are changing or you want to perform complex queries then database is preferred. In case of not changable data use xml. In case of simple data you can even use shared preferences.

Here is short guide to android data storage:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Here is simple tutorial to use hardcoded data with listview:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html